# "cases where null or undefined is coerced into becoming the global object"

Tags: javascript, strict

John Resig [wrote](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/):

> Finally, a long-standing (and very annoying) bug has been resolved: Cases where null or undefined is coerced into becoming the global object. Strict mode now prevents this from happening and throws an exception instead.
>
> `(function(){ ... }).call( null ); // Exception`

what bug is he referring to?

Comment: JR means that `(function(){return this;}).call(null) === window`, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are using the `call()` method from `Function.prototype`, which by default takes scope as the first parameter. If execution scope is `undefined` or `null`, it defaults to the global object. In some situations, using the `call` method with an Immediately Invoked Function Expression(the above code is rather uncommon) doesn't use the global object as the default fallback execution scope.

If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is not coerced to an object. A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The this value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed `this` value to an `Object` (10.4.3, 11.1.1, 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4 clauses of the ECMA language specification).