# Why is `this` set to `window` if I use `function.apply(undefined, args)`?

Tags: javascript, this, apply, window-object

Take a look at this example:

```
function aaa () {
    console.dir(this)
}

function bbb () {}

aaa.apply(undefined, [1,2,3]) // this in aaa is `window` object
aaa.apply(bbb, [1,2,3]) // this in aaa is `bbb` function
```

Why is `this` set to `window` in first apply case, even though I'm trying to force it to be `undefined`?

Comment: Because your function is in sloppy mode.

Comment: Non-"strict mode". Add `"use strict";` before the `console.dir` and it will show `undefined`.

Comment: Never heard of strict mode, thanks. I'll look it up.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997247/1048572, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17150951/1048572 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19804315/1048572

Comment: I've a follow up question now - Should I be worried about strict mode? I've been coding not knowing about it and my apps simply work. I've been calling `.apply(undefined)` for a long time and then using `windows` as `this`. I wonder if I should somehow now check if strict mode is on and then pass `windows` explicitly to apply in case the first value is undefined.......

Comment: @bodacydo - It is highly recommended that you read and learn about strict mode and the differences with non-strict mode and then start using it for all your code.  strict mode will turn some coding mistakes into immediate errors so you see them right away and can fix them rather than attempting to cover them up.

Comment: dont use `undefined` its a *variable* defined on `window`, it can be overridden or not available.

Comment: @LJᛃ can you say that again? undefined is a variable defined on windows? what?

Comment: In older browsers `undefined` was a variable, so one could go and set `window.undefined = "I'm so not undefined bro"`, I just checked and turns out that this is not the case anymore in modern browsers Firefox 4+ etc. so not an issue anymore I guess. Its still not a keyword, so one could create a variable `var undefined = 123` within the scope of a function. I would advise to use `null` instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

When not in strict mode and either `null` or `undefined` is passed as the first argument to `.apply()`, `this` will be set to the global object which is `window` in a browser.

In strict mode, it would set `this` to the actual value you pass.

---

In general non-strict mode tried to be tolerant of mistakes and even "fix" some mistakes automatically for you.  This proved to sometimes be a problem because things that should have been immediate coding errors were "covered up" by the system.  strict mode was invented for a number of reasons and one of the reasons was to stop hiding coding errors.

Comment: Is `undefined` the same as no value? I'm passing it undefined as a value? or is `undefined` not a value?

Comment: I'll have to look up what is strict mode.

Comment: @bodacydo - With some brief testing in Chrome in non-strict mode, "no value" in this case is `null` or `undefined`.  Those values are converted to `window`.  Others are used.

Comment: @bodacydo: Yes, `undefined` is just as good as "no value", when you talk of function calls like `fn.apply()`. In sloppy mode, the `this` value always is an object, so primitive strings, numbers and booleans are wrapped; and instead of `null` or `undefined` the global object is used.

Comment: Very cool. Learning something new every day. What a wonderful experience.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how function calls work if you're not in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).  Without strict mode, a function's `this` reference always refers to an object, and it'll be the global object (i.e. `window`) if no other object was given.